# Problems with Word link to Excel when Windows is set to use UTF-8

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, unicode, utf-8

I've some Word documents that have fields that are automatically updated from an Excel file using Words built-in links to Excel (as in copy > paste special > paste as link).

After setting up a new computer I noticed that in some situations the linked text was being truncated at the end, and with some testing I figured that for each accent char (for example á, õ), or special char (º, ç) in the linked text, a char is removed from the end of that text in Word. If the text as enough special chars a replacement char (�) is added to the end instead.

This all screams of problems with text encoding, but I can't find a way to change that in neither Word or Excel. The only option I see is the language option, but it's set to use the Windows default language in both applications.

So basically I'm looking for a way to check and change the character encoding in Word and Excel.

Additional Info:

- I'm using the latest version of Office 365 with Windows 10, both in pt-PT.
- I tested with other files and blank documents and they all have the same issue, so it's not file dependent.
- The rest of the text in the Word document displays without issues even when using special chars, the issue is only with linked text.
- I'm not able to replicate this issue in other computers, so this might be due to a new Office update, or some machine specific settings.

Comment: There are steps here to check or change the encoding in excel (usually UTF-8): https://www.exceldemy.com/how-to-check-encoding-of-excel-file/. Basically, just unzip the xlsx file, and check the SheetName.xml file for `encoding="UTF-8"` at the top. Same steps for a Word docx (unzip it and check document.xml). In that same document.xml file, you can also search for your linked text to see how exactly word saved it. Check out https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-60d59c21-88b5-4006-831c-d536d42fd861 for more details on Word's encoding options

Comment: Thank you for your help. Figured out that the windows installation came with UTF8 turned on for non-Unicode programs, and that was what's was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by UTF-8 being enabled on the regional settings of the Windows installation. This will cause several errors in other programs, such as:

- Text being truncated
- File not found errors
- Type parse errors
- Replacement chars � shown instead of the intended char

To disable UTF-8 in Windows 10:

- Go to Region settings in the classic Control Panel
- Select the Administrative tab, and click on the Change System Locale Button
- Disable the "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" option
- Restart Windows and wait a few seconds for the new settings to propagate

[image: Disable UTF-8 in Windows 10]